# I have and error in Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Server Error in '/' Application.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web             request. Please review the stack trace for
>   more information about the error and where it   originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an        instance of an object.

```
Source Error: 


Line 29:         <th></th>
Line 30:     </tr>
Line 31:     @foreach (var sections in Model.Sections)
Line 32:     {
Line 33:         <tr>
```

my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TechFactorsLMSV2.Models
{

public class School
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}
public class Section
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnrolled { get; set; }

}

public class LMSDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
}
```

my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TechFactorsLMSV2.Models;

namespace TechFactorsLMSV2.Controllers
{
public class SchoolsController : Controller
{
    private LMSDBContext db = new LMSDBContext();

    //
    // GET: /Schools/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Schools.ToList());
    }
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        var model = db.Schools.Single(d => d.ID == id);
        return View(model);
    }
 } 
}
```

my view

```
 TechFactorsLMSV2.Models.School

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}

<h2>@Model.SchoolName</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Add Section", "Create", "Section", new { SchoolId = @Model.ID }, null      

}

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sections</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var sections in Model.Sections)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@sections.SectionName</td>
        <td>


        </td>

    </tr>
 }


</table>
```

Comment: Did you degub your code? Which line throws this exception? Look at StackTrace..

Comment: So Model.Sections is null? Or Model is null?

Comment: im new to mvc 4 the main error is at the @foreach (var sections in Model.Sections) but i have declared already th model.sections in my model

Comment: whats the possible solutions please help thanks very much

Comment: Use a debugger to step into the code and examine the values of your variables at runtime.

Comment: ive use a debugger and says that my model.sections is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a constructor to your school class that news up the list it'll get rid of the exception, for example;

```
public class School
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }

    public School()
    {
        Sections = new List<Section>();
    }
}
```

But as @Peter says, you need to think about how that's going to be populated, and going through all that isn't for SO.

Comment: am i goind to add that class in my model class?

Comment: You don't have a model class, you have a models namespace with a few classes in it. If you new up your lists in the constructor for each class it wont throw that exception, the lists will be empty as your not populating them... but it wont throw an exception. So if you add the constructor above to your school class that error should go.

Comment: ive added the constructor it works fine but what if i will create a create page for the section still will work fine?

Comment: and it will still populate my sections when i create one?

Comment: It wont populate no, all your doing here is creating an empty list, I advise you follow @Peter's recommendation and watch those tutorial videos as they will help you far more. Would you mark my answer as accepted if I helped you with your original question please. Much appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading up on lazy/eager loading. Your sections are simply never loaded into the model...

Comment: what can i do please thanks!

Comment: @user2122729 check out this video-tutorial: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4-building

Specifically 'listing reviews' under the "Working with Data (Part II)" section. It'll give you the answer *and* explanation. I can recommend the whole series if you want a more complete introduction into MVC4